# When mocking Workbook->Worksheets: variable 'p' of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, mocking, excel-interop

I'm just starting to learn how to use unit testing with NUnit and how to use mocking to fake the objects I need to test.

Currently I'm working with a project that implements a VSTO Excel Addin and would like to start using unit tests with that project.

So I have a function that takes a Workbook as parameter and returns a list of relevant worksheets that I want to process.
This function I would like to test. I "just" need to fake the worksheet names, as that function only iterates through all the worksheets and checking their names.

With searching the internet resources I was trying to build the following solution trying to fake a Workbook with a list of Worksheets with the name list "SheetNames", which is of type List:

```
        var fakeWorksheetList = new List<Excel.Worksheet>();
        foreach (string sheetName in SheetNames)
        {
            var sheet = Mock.Of<Excel.Worksheet>();
            sheet.Name = sheetName;
            fakeWorksheetList.Add(sheet);
        }

        var fakeWorkbook = new Mock<Excel.Workbook>();
        fakeWorkbook.Setup(p => p.Worksheets.GetEnumerator())
            .Returns(() => fakeWorksheetList.GetEnumerator());
```

But when running the test code I get the following error message:

```
variable "p" of type "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook" referenced from scope "", but it is not defined
```

What am I'm doing wrong. Why does the lambda expression in Setup() does give me such an error message?
Is there a better way to fake the Worksheets List?

Please forgive me if I show some lack of understanding as I'm really just starting with the mocking topic.

This is the function I want to test, which I need in my add-in to get all the worksheets my add-in has to work with:

```
    public static Dictionary<int, Excel.Worksheet> GetApplicableYearSheets(Excel.Workbook Workbook, int iCurrentYear = 0)
    {
        if (iCurrentYear <= 0)
            iCurrentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

        int iFromYear = iCurrentYear - 2;
        Dictionary<int, Excel.Worksheet> YearSheets = new Dictionary<int, Excel.Worksheet>();

        for (int iNr = 1; iNr <= Workbook.Worksheets.Count; iNr++)
        {
            int iYear = 0;
            string sWorksheetName = Workbook.Worksheets[iNr].Name;
            if ((sWorksheetName.Trim().Length == 4) && (int.TryParse(sWorksheetName, out iYear)))
            {
                if ((iYear >= iFromYear) && (iYear <= iCurrentYear))
                    YearSheets.Add(iYear, Workbook.Worksheets[iNr]);
            }
        }

        return YearSheets;
    }
```

The sheet names list I want to use for testing, for example is:

```
        List<string> SheetNames = new List<string>()
        {
            "2012",
            "2013",
            "2014",
            "2015",
            "2016",
            "2017",
            "2018",
            "2019",
            "Test",
            "Spezialfälle"
        };
```

My plan was to test calling this function with the mocked fakeWorkbook, for example in the following way:

```
Assert.That(InvoicingUtils.GetApplicableYearSheets(FakeWbFullNames, iCurrentYear: 2019), Has.Exactly(3).Items);
```

and so on

Comment: Can you send your code (just the fragment you want to test? I think you have to mock Worksheets collection as well

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have added the function I want to call to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a better and more elegant way how to write the mocking code but this is working for me.
**Please note:**
 - I use Moq as the mocking framework. I believe you use the same
 - I changed the returning type of your method to `IDictionary` as I had some issues with just `Dictionary`

**The code:**
   - For initializing your test sheets you can use a loop. I just made it simple and created just two sheets without any loop.
   - I think you would be able to get it work with just few setups on the `workbook` object but I like it this way (*just personal preference nothing else*)
   - As you can see the whole logic is ran on the `sheets` object. Basically I get an index from production code, subtracting -1 to get zero based index, save that to my variable `sheetIndex`  and then return back a fake sheet from the `worksheets` collection

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;

namespace ExcelMocking.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private List<Excel.Worksheet> worksheets = new List<Excel.Worksheet>();

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var sheet = new Mock<Excel.Worksheet>();
            sheet.SetupGet(w => w.Name).Returns("2012");
            worksheets.Add(sheet.Object);

            sheet = new Mock<Excel.Worksheet>();
            sheet.SetupGet(w => w.Name).Returns("2013");
            worksheets.Add(sheet.Object);

            var sheetIndex = 0;
            var sheets = new Mock<Excel.Sheets>();
            sheets.Setup(s => s.Count).Returns(() => worksheets.Count);
            sheets.Setup(s => s[It.IsAny<object>()]).Callback<object>((theSheetIndex) =>
            {
                // getting the real sheet index from the production code that starts from 1
                // and simple subtracting -1 to get zero based index
                sheetIndex = (int)theSheetIndex;
                sheetIndex--;
            }).Returns(() => worksheets[sheetIndex]);

            sheets.Setup(s => s.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => worksheets.GetEnumerator());
            sheets.As<Excel.Sheets>().Setup(s => s.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => worksheets.GetEnumerator());

            var workbook = new Mock<Excel.Workbook>();
            workbook.Setup(w => w.Worksheets).Returns(sheets.Object);            

            IDictionary<int, Excel.Worksheet> result = ExcelMocking.Class1.GetApplicableYearSheets(workbook.Object);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you. But I ran into another problem using the IDictionary type. I will check it tomorrow and come back to your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, now it works. Thanks again for your help. I had a strange problem, after changing the return value of the function to IDictionary, when using Dictionary<> for "YearSheets" in my "GetApplicableYearSheets" function, like this:

`Dictionary<int, Excel.Worksheet> YearSheets = new Dictionary<int, Excel.Worksheet>()`
and then trying to add the Worksheet with
`YearSheets.Add(iYear, Workbook.Worksheets[iNr])`

Comment: it returned the following error then:
`Method 'Void Add(Int32, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)' declared on type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.Int32,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet]' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.Int32,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet]'`

when changing the declaration to:
`IDictionary<int, Excel.Worksheet> YearSheets = new Dictionary<int, Excel.Worksheet>();`

Comment: I don't quite get it.. I mean if I declare the variable with IDictionary or Dictionary should actually not matter, isn't it? At runtime it's anyway always of type Dictionary...
And that error happens at runtime, not at compile time..

Comment: You may try to keep the `Dictionary` return type. In my case I couldn't build my test project but if the `Dictionary` works for you just keep it